# Api request still multiple times in set interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
    import axios from "axios";
    import indicator from "trading-indicator";
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    // // GLOBAL MODULES
    // import crypto from "crypto";
    
    // // INSTALLED MODULES
    // import https from "xmlhttprequest";
    // const XMLHttpRequest = https.XMLHttpRequest;
    
    const api = require("binance");
    
    function App() {
      const EMAindicator = indicator.ema;
      const [nextMove, setNextMove] = useState(null);
      const [check, setCheck] = useState(null);
    
      // #######################################################################################################################
      const coin = "BNB";
      const pair = "USDT";
    
      let assetPrice = null;
      const [price, setPrice] = useState(null);
      const binanceRest = new api.BinanceRest({
        key: "API-KEY", // Get this from your account on binance.com
        secret: "SECRET_KEY", // Same for this
        timeout: 15000, // Optional, defaults to 15000, is the request time out in milliseconds
        recvWindow: 10000, // Optional, defaults to 5000, increase if you're getting timestamp errors
        disableBeautification: false,
        handleDrift: true,
        baseUrl: "https://api.binance.com/",
        requestOptions: {},
      });
    
      const checkWalletBalance = async (type) => {
        if (type === coin) {
          await binanceRest.account().then((response) => {
            response.balances.map((el) =>
              el.asset === coin ? setPrice(el.free) : null
            );
          });
          await console.log(type, price);
        } else if (type === pair) {
          await binanceRest.account().then((response) => {
            response.balances.map((el) =>
              el.asset === pair ? setPrice(el.free) : null
            );
          });
    
          await console.log(type, price);
        }
      };
    
      const request = (side) => {
        binanceRest
          .newOrder({
            symbol: coin + pair,
            side: side,
            type: "MARKET",
            quoteOrderQty: price,
          })
          .then((data) => {
            console.table(data);
            console.log(
              `${side}: COIN:${coin} PAIR:${pair} QUOTE_ORDER_QTY: ${price} `
            );
          })
          .catch((err) => console.error(err.message));
      };
    
      const marketBuy = async () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          request("BUY");
        }, 5000);
      };
      const marketSell = async () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          request("SELL");
        }, 5000);
      };
      // #######################################################################################################################
    
      // EXECUTE SELL/BUY
      React.useEffect(() => {
        if (nextMove === "buy") {
          checkWalletBalance(pair).then(() => {
            marketBuy();
          });
        } else if (nextMove === "sell") {
          checkWalletBalance(coin).then(() => {
            marketSell();
          });
        }
      }, [nextMove]);
    
      // EXECUTE BEARISH/BULLISH
      React.useEffect(() => {
        if (check === true) {
          bullish();
        } else if (check === false) {
          bearish();
        }
      }, [check]);
    
      // CHECK BULLISH
      const bullish = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(
          "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=" +
            coin +
            pair +
            "&interval=1m"
        );
        //  BULLISH
        let bullCandle = (await response.data[499][4]) - response.data[498][4] > 0;
        if (bullCandle) {
          await setNextMove("buy");
        }
      };
    
      // CHECK BEARISH
      const bearish = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(
          "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=" +
            coin +
            pair +
            "&interval=1m"
        );
        //  BEARISH
        let bearCandle = response.data[499][4] - response.data[498][4] < 0;
    
        if (bearCandle) {
          await setNextMove("sell");
        }
      };
    
      // MAIN FUNCTION
      const runMachine = async () => {
        try {
          const emaData = await EMAindicator(
            20,
            "close",
            "binance",
            coin + "/" + pair,
            "1m",
            false
          );
    
          const response = await axios.get(
            "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=" +
              coin +
              pair +
              "&interval=1m"
          );
    
          const diff = (await emaData.slice(-1)[0]) - response.data[499][4];
          await console.warn(diff);
    
          if (diff > 0) {
            await setCheck(false);
          } else if (diff < 0) {
            await setCheck(true);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          marketSell();
          await console.log(error.message);
        }
      };
    
      setInterval(() => {
        runMachine();
      }, 20000);
    
      return <h1>TRADE SPOT BINANCE </h1>;
    }
    
    export default App;
```

In this single page component when I try to runMachine function in every 20 seconds 2 api are called multiple times. The objective is to call these API only once in every 20 seconds. Like the function **emaData** under runMachine should be called once but it is called more than once in every 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `runMachine` function you are calling `setCheck` function which updates the component state which causes your component to re-render. This results in `setInterval` being called multiple times. And thats why the `runMachine` function is called multiple times.

You could do the following to resolve your issue.

Note - Clear any/all timers or intervals when the component unmounts.

```js
        import axios from "axios";
        import indicator from "trading-indicator";
        import React, { useState } from "react";
        // // GLOBAL MODULES
        // import crypto from "crypto";
        
        // // INSTALLED MODULES
        // import https from "xmlhttprequest";
        // const XMLHttpRequest = https.XMLHttpRequest;
        
        const api = require("binance");
        let timer = null;
        
        function App() {
          const EMAindicator = indicator.ema;
          const [nextMove, setNextMove] = useState(null);
          const [check, setCheck] = useState(null);
          
          
          .
          .
          .
          .
        
          // MAIN FUNCTION
          const runMachine = async () => {
            try {
              const emaData = await EMAindicator(
                20,
                "close",
                "binance",
                coin + "/" + pair,
                "1m",
                false
              );
        
              const response = await axios.get(
                "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=" +
                  coin +
                  pair +
                  "&interval=1m"
              );
        
              const diff = (await emaData.slice(-1)[0]) - response.data[499][4];
              await console.warn(diff);
        
              if (diff > 0) {
                await setCheck(false);
              } else if (diff < 0) {
                await setCheck(true);
              }
            } catch (error) {
              marketSell();
              await console.log(error.message);
            }
            
            if(timer){
              clearTimeout(timer);
            }
            timer = setTimeout(() => {
              runMachine();
            }, 20000);
          };
          
          if(!timer){
            timer = setTimeout(() => {
              runMachine();
            }, 20000);
          }
        
          return <h1>TRADE SPOT BINANCE </h1>;
        }
        
        export default App;
```

Comment: Any shorter syntax for this what you have done.